# Running Mahout from the command line (CLASSPATH)

Tags: java, classpath, mahout

Complied Mahout successfully under Windows using Maven.

I'm trying to run one of the examples from the command line and I don't get what I am doing wrong. Seems like a CLASSPATH problem.

Let's say I want to run the GroupLensRecommenderEvaluatorRunner example. I go to the folder with the GroupLensRecommenderEvaluatorRunner.class file in it and execute:

```
java -cp C:/mahout/core/target/classes;. 

org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.example.grouplens.GroupLensRecommenderEvaluatorRunner
```

It gives me the NoClassDefFoundError exception for the GroupLensRecommenderEvaluatorRunner
class.

Is the path for -cp wrong?

btw, for those who aren't familiar with mahout,

```
org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.example.grouplens
```

is the package of the GroupLensRecommenderEvaluatorRunner class.
[javadoc](http://people.apache.org/%7Eisabel/mahout_site/mahout-examples/apidocs/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/example/grouplens/GroupLensRecommenderEvaluatorRunner.html)

thanks guys.

p.s - I first looked on previous stackoverflow questions on CLASSPATH and followed the given solutions, before asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is better asked at user@mahout.apache.org.

Your classpath is missing compiled code in Mahout's examples module, which is where this class lives.

Better yet, have a look at this walkthrough: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Recommender+Documentation

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I don't see any classpath explanation in this link.
I do specify the folder  "examples\target\classes\org\apache\mahout\cf\taste\example\grouplens". Any other class files in the examples module?
But it still gives the same thing -- complaining on GroupLensRecommenderEvaluatorRunner
only, not on something else that it cannot find its class file. 

I will keep playing with it and if nothing works i will post the question to the user list. 

thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

If you put `$MAHOUT_HOME/examples/target/classes` is in the java `CLASSPATH` (as Sean mentions) this will work when running locally but you'll probably have to try the method below for a hadoop cluster deployment.

I found the following post very illuminating about how get the right classes in various configurations of mahout/hadoop.

http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/

The mahout script does not accept hadoop job parameters (like --libJar) in all cases although I hope it does in the future, especially where a parameter to the job is a classname (seq2sparse for instance).

What I had to do was copy my custom jar into `$HADOOP_HOME/lib` on the master node. Evidently a symlink does not work, it appears you have to copy each jar you want to the directory.

Then don't forget to stop and start hadoop because as the cloudera reference says it packages the libs at startup.

Comment: That's generally true Pat though the bit of code in question is actually not Hadoop-related.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to set the HADOOP_CLASSPATH with my jar and all the mahout jar files as shown below.

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/home/xxx/my.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-core-0.7-cdh4.3.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-core-0.7-cdh4.3.0-job.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-cdh4.3.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-cdh4.3.0-job.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-integration-0.7-cdh4.3.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.0-1.cdh4.3.0.p0.22/lib/mahout/mahout-math-0.7-cdh4.3.0.jar

Then I was able to run hadoop com.mycompany.mahout.CSVtoVector iris/nb/iris1.csv iris/nb/data/iris.seq

So you have to include all your jars and the mahout jar in the HADOOP_CLASSPATH and then you can just run your class with

`hadoop <classname>`